# What is `elasticsearch data` error mean when searching text in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Kibana 10 to search text on Elasticsearch 10. Sometimes I got below error in Kibana log when searching, but I don't see any logs in Elasticsearch.

I says the error is `elasticsearch data` error and 400 response code on a path `/internal/search/ese`. I wonder is the path points to Elasticsearch? what does this error mean?

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-08-26T06:33:47Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":9,"message":"[status_exception]: error while executing search"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2021-08-26T06:33:47Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"post","statusCode":400,"req":{"url":"/internal/search/ese","method":"post","headers":
...
```

Comment: Actually `elasticsearch` and `data` are just tags, error message is `[status_exception]: error while executing search` and in the second like you can see that query returned 400 Bad Request. It's impossible to anything about this if we don't know what your query was. How were you querying in Kibana?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging and it turns out the issue is Elasticsearch disk space is full. After clean some data it works fine.